# Invite user to install an iOS App using Facebook sdk without FBWebDialogs

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

I have an iOS Bussiness app, which used Facebook to login. Now I have access to the friends list. Is there a way to send a request to a Facebook friend (who is currently not using app) to install my App. My app is Bussiness app category not the game.

Answer (score 1):

this site shows all the information that you want:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2

Comment: my app is not in category of GAME, so i can not use Inviteable-friend to my app.